# Google maps api 3 zoom loads mobile buttons in Chrome on Win8 VM, not regular zoom bar

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, zooming

In a Win8 VM Firefox loads the normal zoom bar, but Chrome does not.  Chrome loads the mobile '+' '-' buttons in the lower left portion of the map.  The light blue buttons (not allowed to post pics, dang).  The mobile zoom buttons do not allow the 'scroll' zooming on the map.

I have tried explicitly setting the map zoom to LARGE, but with no luck:

```
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
   style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
}
```

maps.google.com loads the zoom bar fine in Chrome on the VM.
Additionally, on my Win 7 non-VM the zoom bar loads fine for my site.

Any thoughts?